# MongoDB/Mongoose: Search based on value within a given document without first returning that document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to do a search in MongoDB using either Mongo or Mongoose based on the value of a field in a document.

Let's say I had three MongoDB documents that looked like this:

```
{
  name: "Michael",
  mentored: ["Dwight", "Ryan", "Jim"]
},
{
  name: "Jim",
  mentored: ["Toby", "Roy", "Darryl"]
},
{
  name: "Stanley",
  mentored: ["Pam", "Meredith", "Angela"]
}
```

Let's further say I want to do a search for anyone who Michael has not mentored, which in this case would be Stanley (let's assume that the people in the arrays don't necessarily have their own records). I know I can do a search like this in Mongoose to get the result I want:

```
User.findOne({ name: "Michael" })
.then((person) => {
  const mentored = person.mentored
  return User.find({ name: { $nin: mentored } })
)
.then((person2) => {
  console.log(person2); // Stanley
})
```

However, is there any way to do this without first returning the array from the database and then doing a second search? Something like this:

```
  User.findOne({ name: { $nin: { "Michael's mentored people array" } } })
```

Ultimately I'm looking to see if there's any way to make more efficient such a situation in which arrays can get 10s of thousands of values long. Many thanks.

Comment: I am afraid that it's not possible.

Comment: You could try $lookup to join a collection onto itself and then filter with $not. Your query can be very NOT selective which would result in a huge result set (and corresponding high execution time).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is already efficient for large arrays.

But you could try the following, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62615841/mongodb-mongoose-search-based-on-value-within-a-given-document-without-first-re#comment110732066_62615841) by @D.SM. but using aggregation the intermediate results will have to be loaded in memory, which does not seem efficient to me.

```
User.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: "Michael"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      as: "notMentored",
      let: {
        mentored: "$mentored",
/*
You probably want to remove "Michael" from the result, one way is to add him to the mentored array
        mentored: { $concatArrays: ["$mentored", ["$name"]]}
*/
      },
      pipeline: [{
        $match: {
          $expr: { $not: { $in: ["$name", "$$mentored"] } }
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$notMentored"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$notMentored"
    }
  }
])
```